# where is my java file?

Tags: ubuntu-9.04

I'm using ubuntu and I call gedit by using this command:'sudo gedit filename.java'. I'm newbie in ubuntu so now I can not located that file. Ah I'm using windows XP and ubuntu and I have three disk C,D and E in windows XP the fourth disk for ubuntu is not display in windows XP.  Can anyone show me where I can find my file? Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for reading my trouble, now I have found it on the folder /home/username(in my case my username is hiepnq ) so /home/hiepnq/. Thank you again!

Comment: dont use sudo for editing source code though, there shouldn't be any reason to do that as the 'root' user

Answer (score 2):

Try looking up the command "[find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)".  It will locate files.

Answer (score 1):

The next time you need to find a file and you don't know where it is, just use the `locate` program included with Ubuntu. Sure, your file most likely won't show up immediately in the slocate database, but it's a really good searcher.

Also, the command line and the run prompt assume that the starting point, that is, the current working directory is always "~" unless you've set it differently. That means that all files and paths are relative to your home folder: /home/username for a user and /root for the root user.

Finally, you do not need to use the sudo command for writing code in your own home directory, and thus you can just stick with `gedit filename.java.` However, if you ever do need to use a graphical application with root/superuser privileges, use `gksu` for GTK apps and `kdesu` for KDE apps. `sudo` is for when you are running an program or need elevated privileges in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Type "man find" into the terminal to get a description of how to use the command. But first place I'd look is the home folder. Open up the terminal and type "~" without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal again ( from where you initially typed sudo ) and type ls -l you have to find it there.